# VBA replace text without replacing other words that contain similar text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use "*" as a wildcard for data in Column F. All the data is in the same format and length as "Pie**" where each "*" represents (0-9)

Example: Pie22, Pie71, Pie15, Hot22, Hot41, Hot98

When I try the code below, I run into the issue where CoffeeXX is finding and replacing "Hot" in "hotdog" and it becomes "chickendog".

Is there a was to fix this so that the .find sees the wildcard instead of just picking anything that contains the text?

```
Set PieXX = Columns("F").Find(What:="Pie**", Lookin:=xlvalues)
If not PieXX is nothing then
Columns("F").Replace What:"Pie**", replacement:="Hotdog", _
SearchOrder:=xlbyrows, Matchcase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, Replaceformat:=false
End If

    Set CoffeeXX = Columns("F").Find(What:="Hot**", Lookin:=xlvalues)
If not CoffeeXX is nothing then
Columns("F").Replace What:"Hot**", replacement:="Chicken", _
SearchOrder:=xlbyrows, Matchcase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, Replaceformat:=false
End If
```

Comment: I think you want the `?` wildcard (which matches a single character) rather than the `*` wildcard (which matches multiple characters).  I assume that, if `*` is permitted in a `Find`, `?` will be permitted too.

Comment: Do this in a loop for every cell in the range `if cell.value like "pie??" then cell.Replace "pie", "hi", LookAt:=xlPart`. This should only replace text in a cell with "pie" followed by 2 characters and will only replace the "pie" part of the text. I think this is what you want?

Comment: Well I just learned that if I accidentally triple click a comment's "upvote" then the upvote doesn't count and can _never_ be up-voted again. <sub>(silly.)</sub>  Anyhow, **+1++ to what @YowE3K said.  Your statement `sees the wildcard instead of just picking anything` is self-contradictory since _that's what wildcards do_ but you indeed probably meant `?`.  Here are the basics on ["Wildcard Characters used in VBA String Comparisons"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/wildcard-characters-used-in-string-comparisons).

Comment: I tried replacing the "*" with a "?". However, I still run into the same issue. Also, I'm not to familiar with VBA to add the `if cell.value like "pie??" then cell.Replace "pie", "hi", LookAt:=xlPart`

Answer (score 2):

```
For each cell in Range("F1", Range("F1").End(xlDown))
    If cell.value like "pie??" then cell.Replace "pie", "hi", LookAt:=xlPart
Next
```

This is untested

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the fix. I don't have enough comments/posts to up vote.